# Using catch to assign a new integer value

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, numberformatexception

I would like to set a text vale from a TextField and convert to an integer.  When the integer is converted, I would like to get a value (n).  If an integer value is not entered, for instance a string or character, how do I create an exception to make the default value of the integer (n) = 3?

```
private void Game(){

int n = 0;

String getsize;     

getsize = size.getText();

//gets the text position and turns into integer
try{
    n = Integer.parseInt(getsize);
}

catch(NumberFormatException e){
    n = 3;
    e.printStackTrace();
}

...
}
```

Comment: Your code resembles what you're asking. What's the problem?

Comment: What's your problem? Aside from naming conventions and formatting your code looks just fine.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I figured it out, I needed to add that same code to my action handler method.  thanks.

Comment: @jlordo figured it out, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could change your line

```
int n=0;
```

to

```
int n = 3;
```

That way, if the try block fails **before or during** the `parseInt`, `n` will remain as 3.